# Django - How to increase the number of choices in a (multiple) select field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

By default, the number of options in a select field is 4, is there an option to increase this number? To 5 or 6 perhaps?

Edit:

My model -->

```
class Other(models.Model):
    txt = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES) #CHOICES is a dynamically generated list of tuples from a database query

    class Meta:
    db_table = 'my_table'
    ordering = ['txt']

class Main(models.Model):

    #Other fields..
    other = models.ManyToManyField(Other)
```

Html -->

```
//I use the 'Main' model that is represented as 'form' in the html code

//....

{{ form.other.label }}<br>
{{ form.other }}

//rest of html....
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no "default" number of options, it will show what you give it. Maybe you could clarify, what does your model/form look like and what html is produced from that code?

Comment: @Ngenator, I have added additional details. Please let me know if more are necessary.

Comment: Take a look at @Rohan's answer, sorry I didn't get a chance to read your reply sooner.

Answer (score 1):

`choices` for model field cannot be a callable, rather it should be tuple/list. Overriding it through `__init__()` method as is generally done for forms is not recommended for models.

You may want to re-design your models. You can create another model for choices that you have and have `ForeignKey()` relationship with `Other` model.

What you might have seeing about number of choices is the number of choices that are present when that model class is initialized.